# How do i get all pending tasks to show in celery flower task view?

Tags: celery, flower

I'm currently running celery 5 with flower 1.0.0 with redis as both broker and backend.

Only tasks that are in their final result/tombstone state are visible in flower. Is there an additional configuration change that I need to enable?

```
celery -A main worker --hostname=annotate_@%h --pool=solo --task-events
```

```
flower   -> flower:1.0.0 tornado:6.1 humanize:3.10.0
software -> celery:5.1.0 (sun-harmonics) kombu:5.1.0 py:3.10.0b1
            billiard:3.6.4.0 py-amqp:5.0.6
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF
            kernel version:5.4.0-1051-azure imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled

deprecated_settings: None
```

```
worker configuration:

app = Celery(broker='redacted',
    backend='redis://redacted'
)
app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.task_default_queue = 'redacted'
app.conf.task_track_started = True
app.conf.task_send_sent_event = True
app.conf.worker_send_task_events = True
app.conf.worker_hijack_root_logger = False
app.conf.worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
app.conf.worker_enable_remote_control = True
app.conf.result_expires = 60 * 60 * 2 # 2 hour TTL in seconds
```

The following is a snapshot of a few finished tasks, but the queue itself has 10+ pending & in 'progress'.

[image]